# Malware in Knockoutjs context debugger

Tags: knockout.js

Has anyone else seen this:[image]

Is there another extension for KnockoutJs?

Comment: Looks like it was removed from the Chrome Web Store on Nov 22nd due to this very reason

Comment: I noticed this as well but couldn't find any information about *why* - I'm wondering if it's actually a heuristic thing because the extension would be looking at what the browser is doing in detail?

Comment: Not just heuristics, there is a large change between 2.6.6 & 2.6.7 of the extension (when the original Maintainer, archive the source repo). [Comparison of the "malware" detected changes](https://github.com/SamJUK/chromeextensions-knockoutjs-malware/compare/2.6.6...2.6.7#diff-ffa5b716b5a57837f7929dfcca4b4dfdeb97210a7fd5a12d2f1978846d6f1743)

Comment: Is there another tool anyone else is using? or have they found a workaround? Im facing same issue and this tool was pretty vital to debugging knockout for me.

Answer (score 4):

@sam-james is right, someone else seam to have published a version on chrome store which is not the same as the one on GitHub.

I cloned the GitHub repo (https://github.com/timstuyckens/chromeextensions-knockoutjs) and added it from source. The repo is inactive and has not been changed since Dec 9, 2022, where the version was updated to 2.6.6.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the knockout.context.debugger still works in Firefox, at 2.6.3.

If you want to go this route, at least for now, you can go here and add the extension:

[knockout.context](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/knockoutjs-context/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search)

Also, until issues with the extension are resolved, I went into 'Manage Extension' set the following:

Allow automatic update s= 'off'